# Creating if for dblclick td

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a problem. I'm trying to put premisions. How can I make that if user id is equal to task creator id, then allow the user to use onClick functions, if not then don't. I've tried doing this UserNow is the now user, and the userown is creator:

```
    if (UserNow == UserOwn) {
        function editCellValue(cellElement) {
```

But this ddnt worked, i think that i should do this in this:

```
 $s .= ('<td class="select0" id="start_'.$currentTasken.'" nowrap="nowrap" align="center" ondblclick="mouseCords(event);editCellValue(this)" style="' . $style . '; border: none;" title="'.$AppUI->_('Double click to edit date').'">' 
       . $NewStartData . '</td>
```

For example:

```
ondblclick="if(UserNow == UserOwn) { mouseCords(event);editCellValue(this) }"
```

But I don't know how it write correctly. So that is my question, how can make if for dblclick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to remove ondblclick attribute on html.

```
 $s .= ('<td class="select0" id="start_'.$currentTasken.'" nowrap="nowrap" align="center" style="' . $style . '; border: none;" title="'.$AppUI->_('Double click to edit date').'">' 
   . $NewStartData . '</td>
```

And write it in javascript (this is an example with jQuery)

```
 $('td').on('dblclick', function(e) {
      if(UserNow === UserOwn) {
          editCellValue($(this));
      }
 });

 function editCellValue(cellElement) { ....
```